# Can i enable GPU visualization? (in WPF)

Tags: wpf

In Silverlight there was an abillity to visualize GPU rendering.

eg: elements that was rendered on GPU would highlight in Magenta while everything else was normal colored.

Is there a similar feature for WPF ?
To make sure that what I'm trying to optimize is actually doing what i want it to ..

edit:
I found the function in Silvelright, it's called EnableCacheVisualization and apparantly this doesn't apply to WPF because WPF is running directly on GPU...

I wonder if there is a repaint / redraw visualizer instead like in browsers, which helps me find problems...

Comment: if WPF is running directly on GPU, it looks like everything would be in magenta color with the visualization, so kind of problem is solved?

Comment: yeah but it would be nice with some kind of hint about what elements are causing problems or not running like they are supposed to... 

Right now i have a performance problem and dont know where to start.

Comment: for that I would suggest using a profiler, and start logging thread Id. Performance problems in WPF in 99% come from running too much code on the main thread. Clicking a button in best case scenarion should just publish a trigger to action, which should be done in bakgroung. Rx are great for that (checkout [ReactiveCommand](https://www.reactiveui.net/docs/handbook/commands/))

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I know how and when to offload heavy tasks to a thread different from UI. To be more specific, I'm developing an App that uses Telerik RadGrid, which has some performance issues. Their guide to improve the performance is to get rid of setups that disables UI Virtualizations - It's however quite a task to identify the sinners without any visual tools :(

Comment: Virtualization is completely different thing. Virtualization meas that if you have a list of 1000 elements and only 4 are visible, than you create UI objects (like their ContentTemplate) only 4 times. Then, when you scroll, you reuse those objects, or even create new ones, but only for visible elements. You can read up on that. WPF does not provide that out of the box

Comment: I know what Scrollpanel Virtualization is - and it shows via Repaint/Redraw. if virtualization is off, there will be no repaint/redraw of the scrolling area.